# AWS CLI: ECR list-images, get newest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Using AWS CLI, and jq if needed, I'm trying to **get the tag of the newest image in a particular repo**.

Let's call the repo `foo`, and say the latest image is tagged `bar`. What query do I use to return `bar`?

I got as far as

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name foo
```

and then realized that the [list-images documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/list-images.html) gives no reference to the date as a queryable field. Sticking the above in a terminal gives me keypairs with just the tag and digest, no date.

Is there still some way to get the "latest" image? Can I assume it'll always be the first, or the last in the returned output?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use [`describe-images`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-images.html) instead.

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo
```

returns `imagePushedAt` which is a timestamp property which you can use to filter.

I dont have examples in my account to test with but something like following should work

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo \
--query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*]'
```

If you want another flavor of using sort method, you can review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156165/4296747)

Comment: Thank you! Worth noting this works only on awscli 1.11+.

Comment: this one worked for me: `aws ecr describe-images --output json --repository-name $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' | jq . --raw-output`. Without `jq` few repos were showing 2 images.

Comment: not sure why but I am getting multiple image versions. Im using `| tr '\t' '\n' | head` to get the first version

Comment: In my case this returned multiple versions, but that was because the image got tagged many times, when our builds resulted in the same image.

Comment: This sorts ascending, giving the newest first.  You can fix that by adding `reverse(sort_by(...`  BUT, it still only sorts the first page of output when there's a long paginated list.  So it doesn't work if you have a lot of entries.

Comment: Thanks Varun Chandak for correct answer.

Answer (score 43):

To add to Frederic's answer, if you want the latest, you can use [-1]:

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo \
--query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]'
```

Assuming you are using a singular tag on your images... otherwise you might need to use `imageTags[*]` and do a little more work to grab the tag you want.

Comment: aws ecr describe-images --repository-name gnk-stage-ar --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]'
1550
1553
latest
1558
1547
1511
new-13
1541
1545
1561
1563
1557
1534
1539
1562
1554

Its not printing the latest image number. but same command is working in ubuntu not in centos

Comment: Add `--no-paginate` if you have a lot of tags.

Answer (score 6):

To get only latest image with out special character minor addition required for above answer.

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' --output text
```

Answer (score 5):

**List latest X images pushed to ECR**

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name gvh \
--query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].imageTags[0]' --output yaml \
| tail -n 3 | awk -F'- ' '{print $2}'
```

**List first X images pushed to ECR**

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name gvh \
--query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].imageTags[0]' --output yaml \
| head -n 3 | awk -F'- ' '{print $2}'
```

Number 'X' can be generalized in either head or tail command based on user requirement

Answer (score 3):

Without having to sort the results, you can filter them specifying the imageTag=latest on image-ids, like so:

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo --image-ids imageTag=latest --output text
```

This will return only one result with the newest image, which is the one tagged as `latest`

Answer (score 3):

Some of the provided solutions will fail because:

- There is no image tagged with 'latest'.
- There are multiple tags available, eg. [1.0.0, 1.0.9, 1.0.11]. With a sort_by this will return 1.0.9. Which is not the latest.

Because of this it's better to check for the image digest.

You can do so with this simple bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -
#===============================================================================
#
#          FILE: get-latest-image-per-ecr-repo.sh
#
#         USAGE: ./get-latest-image-per-ecr-repo.sh aws-account-id
#
#       AUTHOR: Enri Peters (EP)
#       CREATED: 04/07/2022 12:59:15
#=======================================================================

set -o nounset       # Treat unset variables as an error

for repo in \
        $(aws ecr describe-repositories |\
        jq -r '.repositories[].repositoryArn' |\
        sort -u |\
        awk -F ":" '{print $6}' |\
        sed 's/repository\///')
do
        echo "$1.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/${repo}@$(aws ecr describe-images\
        --repository-name ${repo}\
        --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageDigest' |\
        tr -d '"')"
done > latest-image-per-ecr-repo-${1}.list
```

The output will be written to a file named `latest-image-per-ecr-repo-awsaccountid.list`.

An example of this output could be:

```
123456789123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-ecr-repository-name@sha256:fb839e843b5ea1081f4bdc5e2d493bee8cf8700458ffacc67c9a1e2130a6772a
...
...
```

With this you can do something like below to pull all the images to your machine.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -

for image in $(cat latest-image-per-ecr-repo-353131512553.list)
do
    docker pull $image
done
```

You will see that when you run `docker images` that none of the images are tagged. But you can 'fix' this by running these commands:

`docker images --format "docker image tag {{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:latest" > tag-images.sh`

`chmod +x tag-images.sh`

`./tag-images.sh`

Then they will all be tagged with `latest` on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

This will check for ECR latest tags and return the TAG name

aws ecr describe-images --repository-name api-prod  --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' --output text

Answer (score -1):

To get the latest image tag use:-

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo --query 'imageDetails[*].imageTags[ * ]' --output text | sort -r | head -n 1
```

Comment: This doesn't return the latest image. For eg., if you have 1.13.0 and 1.9.0, it will return 1.9.0

Comment: As per the other comment, your 'sort' depends on the name of the image, which may or may not be in order.