# Docker Image tagging in ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

I am pushing docker image in AWS ECR using Jenkins.

While pushing the image I am providing tag as $Build_Number. So in ECR repo I have images with tags like 1,2,3,4.

But when I am trying to pull the image from EC2 with below command from Jenkins job

```
docker pull 944XXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository1:latest
```

I am getting an error as there is no image with tag as latest.

Here I want to pull the latest image (with tag 4). I cannot hard-code tag number here as docker pull command will run from Jenkins job automatically. So what way can I pull the latest image?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe that the correct approach here would be to push the same image twice with different tags. One push would include the image with no tag and then the second push would be the same image after you have tagged it.

Note that you don't have to build the image twice. You only need to issue the `docker push` twice.

ECR is "smart" enough to recognise that the image digest did not change and it will not try to actually upload the image twice. On the second push only the tag will be send to ECR.

Now that you have an untagged version and a tagged version, you can pull the image without the tag specification and you will get the `:latest` image. [Here is a reference to the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html#image-tag-step) where they mention that the `:latest` tag will be added if no tag was sent by the user.

The flow would look something like this:

```bash
# Build the image
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t my-web-app
# Push the untagged image (will become the ":latest")
docker push my-web-app
# Tag the image with your build_number
docker tag my-web-app my-web-app:build_number
# Push the tagged image 
docker push my-web-app:build_number
```

You will now be able to:

```bash
docker pull my-web-app:build_number
docker pull my-web-app
```

Which will result in 2 identical images with only the tag differentiating between them.

Comment: we want to put the images with Build_number or Artifact_id so that they can be identified latter.Also all the images in ECR should have tag.Hence i cannot push with tag "latest".Is there any other way possible ?

Comment: What I mean is that the most recent image will be accessible via both the Build_number/Artifact_id as well as using `:latest`. I've updated my answer to include more details...

Comment: Got it.Thanks for detailed Explanation :)

Comment: You can tag an image when building and you can add multiple tags at once. You then need just 2 commands: 
docker build -t 944XXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository1:100 - t 944XXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository1:latest 
docker push 944XXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository1

Answer (score 5):

one solution is suggested by @Lix that you can try, or if you are interested with just latest pushed image and no matter whats the tag of a latest image then you can get the latest image from AWS-CLI.

So your Jenkins job command will be

```
TAG=$(aws ecr describe-images --output json --repository-name stage/redis --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' | jq . --raw-output)
docker pull 944XXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository1:$TAG
```

[aws-cli-ecr-list-images-get-newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331418/aws-cli-ecr-list-images-get-newest)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `latest` tag on ECR, you need to add it and push it there when you build the image.  You can use the `-t` to `docker build` multiple times (see https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/build/); just make sure to push them all.

Comment: If the only thing changing with the image is the tag there is no need to rebuild it.

Comment: true, but if you're building it anyway, there's also no need to retag it either.